# making valgrind happy vs avoiding segfault

Tags: c, malloc, free

I'm new to C, trying to learn dynamic memory allocation for an array of char arrays, and not sure why I can't make valgrind happy with 0 errors also whilst avoiding a segfault. My example is based on this example:

[How to dynamically allocate memory for char** in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786387/how-to-dynamically-allocate-memory-for-char-in-c)

From that example, I whipped up this test code below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
        char **myChar;

        int nEl = 5;
        int nChars = 10;

        myChar = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
        for (int it = 0; it < nEl; it++) {
                myChar[it] = (char*)malloc((nChars) * sizeof(char));
        }

        //for (int it = 0; it < nEl; it++) {
        //        free(myChar[it]);
        //}
        //free(myChar);

        return 0;
}
```

It compiles as is, runs without problem, exits with return 0x0, but valgrind complains:

```
4 errors in context 1 of 1:
Invalid write of size 8
   at 0x400583: main (in /home/username/Documents/personal/tmp/cprog2/test2)
 Address 0x5204048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
   at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
   by 0x40054D: main (in /home/username/Documents/personal/tmp/cprog2/test2)

ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Figuring that valgrind expects the malloc'd **myChar and myChar[it] to be free(), I uncomment the commented bits, but the program segfaults and valgrind says this:

```
4 errors in context 1 of 2:
Invalid read of size 8
   at 0x4005EF: main (in /home/username/Documents/personal/tmp/cprog2/test2)
 Address 0x5204048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
   at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
   by 0x40058D: main (in /home/username/Documents/personal/tmp/cprog2/test2)


4 errors in context 2 of 2:
Invalid write of size 8
   at 0x4005C3: main (in /home/username/Documents/personal/tmp/cprog2/test2)
 Address 0x5204048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
   at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
   by 0x40058D: main (in /home/username/Documents/personal/tmp/cprog2/test2)

ERROR SUMMARY: 8 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Why can I not make valgrind happy and compile and run a working app?

Comment: `myChar = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));` you allocate (space for) a single pointer, not 5.

Comment: Tip: `sizeof(char)` is garanteed to be `1`. No need to multiply by `1`.

Comment: Use `ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * nElmenets);`  Easy to code review and maintain.

Comment: Thanks all, that's painfully obvious now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allocated enough memory:

```
myChar = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

This allocates space for a single `char *`, but you treat this memory as if you allocated 5 (i.e. `nEl`) of them.

As a result, you write past the end of allocated memory.  This is what Valgrind is alerting you of when it says "Address 0x5204048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd".  Doing so invokes undefined behavior, which in this case manifests as a crash.

If you want space for `nEl` pointers, allocate that amount of space:

```
myChar = malloc(sizeof(char*) * nEl);
```

Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding the casting the return from malloc, I am getting error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive] if I don't cast the return. I'll have to do some more reading in the thread you linked to fully understand why that is

Comment: @brneuro That probably means you're compiling as C++ instead of C.

Comment: ah, indeed I am as I'm working toward implementing some of this into a class.